# Where is the framing in a flat roof overhang?

Tags: framing

I want to attach a lag eyebolt into a roof overhang to string some lights to. However, I'm not sure of the construction behind the flashing, and I don't want to drill and caulk any more holes than I need to.

All I can see peeking behind the flashing is OSB, so I'm not sure where the framing is. What would typical construction for something like this be?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you can remove one of the recessed lights, you might be able to tell the direction of beams running. At least you would know the thickness of the ceiling board/panel, it might be able to handle the small hanging weights.

Comment: Three options, 1) look for nails / screws - that paneling has to be held on to something. 2) Invest in a stud finder. 3) if the lights aren't too heavy then toggle bolts might be an option.